# PowerShell Parsing Name and Version out of a String

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to parse the name and the version of a string.

The schema of the string is the following:

EntityFramework.6.2.0

EntityFramework.Functions.1.4.1

What I want to have is an array or an object with the name of the package and the version.

The version number can have 1,2,3 or 4 digits and the name can also have "."

```
$version = @()
$name = @()

"EntityFramework.Functions.1.4.1".Split('.') | % {
  if ($_ -match "^\d+$"){
   $version += $_
  }else{
    $name += $_
  }
}

$name -join "."
$version -join "."
```

This works but I think there is a better way to do it.

Any Idea to short this snippet or make it more smart.

Comment: Ok, I added my working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be improved by just relying on regex from the start:

```
$null = 'EntityFramework.Functions.1.4.1' -match '(?<name>[^\d]+)(?<version>\d.+)'
$name, $version = $Matches['name'].TrimEnd('.'), [version]$Matches['version']

$name
>> EntityFramework.Functions

$version
>> Major  Minor  Build  Revision
>> -----  -----  -----  --------
>> 1      4      1      -1
```

Explained:

```
(           // Capture a group  
  ?<name>   // Name it "name"
    [^\d]+  // Capture until you find a digit
)           // End capture group

(             // Capture a group
  ?<version>  // Name it "version"
    \d.+      // Start at a digit and wildcard catch everything after
)             // End capture group
```

---

Shortened (for haxxorz):

```
if ('EntityFramework.Functions.1.4.1' -match '(.*?(?=\.\d))\.(.+)')
{
    $name, [version]$version = $matches[1, 2]
}
```

(gottagoshort):

```
$name,$version='EntityFramework.Functions.1.4.1'-split'(?<=[^\d])\.(?=\d)'
```

Comment: Nice, this looks like smart. Thank you for the improvement.

Comment: @Wimpy I updated my answer with the `if` check, but I also suggest looking at mklement0's answer for an even better solution.

Comment: I found a special case which not work with your improvement. Could you check the string with your regex solution. System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.2

Answer (score 2):

Note: This is an optimized variation of the original answer below, courtesy of [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1).

By using the **`-split` operator** with **a separator regex that uses *lookaround assertions***, it is possible to split the string in the desired location with a single operation:

```
# Stores 'EntityFramework.Functions' in $name
# and '1.4.1' in $version
$name, $version = "EntityFramework.Functions.1.4.1" -split '(?<=[^\d])\.(?=\d)'
```

- `(?<=[^\d])\.(?=\d)` uses a look-*behind* assertion (`(?<=...)` and a look-*ahead* assertion (`(?=...)`) to provide the desired context for matching the literal `.` (`\.`):

  - The regex matches the `.` only if *preceded* by a character that is *not* a digit (`[^\d]`) and is *followed* by a digit, which is where we want to split: between the end of the package name and the start of the version number.
  - Regex assertions in general do not *capture* characters, so that even though the surrounding character are *looked at*, it is only the `.` that is considered the separator, ensuring that the tokens on either side of it are returned in full.
- The result of the `-split` operation is a 2-element array, whose elements can be assigned to indidvidual variables via a destructuring assignment (`$name, $version = ...`)

---

**Original answer**:

Note: While the regex used below is slightly shorter than the one above, its interplay with `-split` is actually conceptually more complex, and the solution requires an additional operation to filter out an empty result element (`-ne ''`).

A more concise solution that uses the `-split` operator with a regex (regular expression):

```
# Stores 'EntityFramework.Functions' in $name
# and '1.4.1' in $version
$name, $version = "EntityFramework.Functions.1.4.1" -split '^([^\d]+)\.' -ne ''
```

- `^([^\d]+)\.` starts matching at the start of the string (`^`) and matches one or more (`+`) non-digit characters (`[^\d]`) followed by a literal `.` (`\.`)

  - This matches `EntityFramework.Functions.`, but, due to enclosing only the part *before* the trailing `.` in `(...)` to form a capture group, only `EntityFramework.Functions` is returned.
    (By default, what the separator regex matches is *not* returned - after all, you just want the tokens *between* the separators - but a *capture group* embedded in the regex can be used to deliberate include part of the separator in the result array).
  - The separator regex is by definition not found again in the input string (because it is anchored at the start of the string with `^`, so the remainder of the string - `1.4.1` - is considered the 2nd and only remaining token.
- `-ne ''` filters out the empty first element of the resulting array that is a side effect of the string *starting with a match* of the separator regex expression.

  - In the typical case your regex matches just the separators and doesn't include them (or parts of them) in the result array; thus, unless the input truly starts with a separator instance or you have adjacent separators, you won't get empty elements; e.g., `'foo,bar;baz' -split '[,;]'` yields `'foo', 'bar', 'baz'`, without empty elements.

Comment: Will the `-split` always generate an empty string?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: No, only if the string starts with something that matches the separator regex.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: I've added an explanation to your variant, but I've also kept the original answer, because juxtaposing the two approaches may be interesting. The look-around regex, while slightly longer, is not only preferable because you don't need the `ne ''`, but it is also conceptually simpler in the context of `-split`. Thanks for making this answer better.

Answer (score 0):

```
@(
'EntityFramework.6.2.0',
'EntityFramework.Functions.1.4.1'
) | %{

    [pscustomobject]@{
        name = $_ -replace '\.([0-9]).*([0-9])$'
        version = $_ -replace '^([A-Za-z]).*([A-Za-z])\.'
    }
}
```

This separates each item based on a group of character types.